# I need a pop-up to appear when a new item has been added to a custom list

Tags: events, popup

We have built a SharePoint environment in SharePoint 2013 Online (in Office 365).
Within this environment we have a site with a custom list with various columns.

I know we can create a view which filters the list on specific content in a column.
But what we would like to publish is a pop-up which shows up when a new item has been added OR an item has changed the value from X to Y (predefined).

The popup should contain the content of the item.

Since it is SharePoint Online we would like to use jQuery or alternatives to accomplish this feature.

Which solution and which code would you recommend?

Comment: what do you want to show in the pop-up? You can use jquery to do the same.

Comment: I would like it to show a message with the content of the item.

Answer (score 2):

I have done the below in SharePoint 2010, hope it will work in SharePoint 2013 also.
To bring a Pop UP, you can make use of `PreSaveAction` function in your newform.aspx. 
In the newform.aspx of the list, you have to use content editor web part with the below javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction() {
 alert('Thank you for the submission');
 return true;
} 
</script>
```

It actually overrides the PreSaveAction method of newform.aspx in the javascript.

**NOTE:**

- PreSaveAction and PreSaveItem does processing before the item is committed to the
  database.
- In the Editform.aspx of the list, you can use the same code and
  replace `PreSaveAction` with the `PreSaveItem()`

Comment: unfortunately this isn't the solution I was seeking for, the script you provided sends an pop-up based on the user submitting a new item.
What we're looking for is a notification when an item is just added (for example by someone else)

Answer (score 0):

the solution would be to use visual studios to create a feature, within the feature you need to create an item event reciver for added and updated (NOT adding and updating)

within those two you need to call a custom method that will pull out the info that you just added to the list from the properties..... You can then go ahead and create your JS file that you can add and store within 15hive underlayouts. The JS will activate every time a item is added or updated.

You need to add to the page:

to bind the script to page:

```
    private string BindScript(string ScriptUrl, bool PickFromSiteCollection)
    {
        if (PickFromSiteCollection)
            ScriptUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url, ScriptUrl);
        else
            ScriptUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Web.Url, ScriptUrl);
        return string.Format(@"<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""{0}""></script>", ScriptUrl);
    }
```

to call the method above with your custom JS file:

```
    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write(BindScript("/_LAYOUTS/1033/customJS/Javascript/myFile.js", true));
        base.Render(writer);
    }
```

for the JS popup you can use karthik method:

```
 function popitup(listItem1,listitem2) {
       alert('Thank you for the submission', 'You have entered: ' + listItem1 + 'and' + listitem2);
       return true;
 }
```

change your js code to what ever you like ;) , add the varibles to the function. iv done 
listItem1,listitem2 for simplicity. If you dont want an alert than you can make it yourself like making the div element appear as a popup rather than a modal box!

this method requires some code to be added to the page like the list:

http://sivanandareddyg.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/popup-div-tag-with-close-button-using.html

its not hard to figure out how to incorporate the above to my solution ;) only need to change a few thing to get it working!

copy past the js in that example to your js file, copy past the css from that example into a custom css file and ammend the js call to call the function.

you need to also add this to add the css:

//bind the css file to the page:

```
    private string BindStyle(string StyleUrl, bool PickFromSiteCollection)
    {
        try
        {
            if (PickFromSiteCollection)
                StyleUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url, StyleUrl);
            else
                StyleUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Web.Url, StyleUrl);
            return string.Format(@"<link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""{0}"" type=""text/css"" />", StyleUrl);
        }
        catch(Exception a)
        {
            reportError.WriteError("Control ID: " + a.Source, a.Message, " BindStyle: at " + a.StackTrace, SPContext.Current.Site.Url);
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

to call the method above:

add this line also within the render method:

```
writer.Write(BindStyle("/_layouts/1033/customcss/mycss.css", true));
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351771/open-popup-window-using-javascript

call the JS file by adding this within your custom method:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "MyUniqueKey", "popitup("+ listItem1 + "," + listitem2  +");", true);
```

as you can see im passing the values. Obviously its wrong in my case ;) you have the properties to get the current item to pass.

so for item added and updated its:

```
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);
        //call custom method passing the item properties
        mycustommethod(properties);
    }

    public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemUpdated(properties);
        //call custom method passing the item properties
        mycustommethod(properties);
    }


    private void mycustommethod(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
           //call JS code also pass the properties of the list accross!
           string itemId = properties.ListItem["ID"].ToString();
           string itemName = properties.ListItem["Name"].ToString();


           Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "MyUniqueKey", "popitup("+ itemId + "," + itemName +");", true);

    }

    private string BindScript(string ScriptUrl, bool PickFromSiteCollection)
    {
        if (PickFromSiteCollection)
            ScriptUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url, ScriptUrl);
        else
            ScriptUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Web.Url, ScriptUrl);
        return string.Format(@"<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""{0}""></script>", ScriptUrl);
    }

    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write(BindScript("/_LAYOUTS/1033/customJS/Javascript/myFile.js", true));
        base.Render(writer);
    }
```

Comment: I wonder, It is possible to write event receivers in SharePoint 2013 online?

Comment: yes you can but instead its called Remote Event Receivers